# Number of setbits(x or y) + Number of setbits(x and y) = m. Is there any way to solve this equation, to find relation between x and y?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, 64-bit, bit, puzzle

I have been asked one question in the HackerEarth coding platform, to find pairs x and y from the arrays that satisfy the above equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a useful property of `setbits`:

```
setbits(x | y) + setbits(x & y) == setbits(x) + setbits(y)
```

This is true because the OR and the AND pair sort of "redistribute" the bits without changing the total number of set bits. For example consider 1-bit numbers:

```
x y   x&y x|y
0 0    0   0
0 1    0   1
1 0    0   1
1 1    1   1
```

On every row, `x&y` and `x|y` together have as many set bits as `x` and `y` together.

With that, the problem is really equivalent to finding pairs of numbers that add up to `m` (this has been covered in other questions on this website), and the `setbits` aspect is just a distraction.